# Nothing returned when deserializing user in node and passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to login my user in the node application, using OrientDB as the database and node js and express. I have imported passport actually adopted the solution from one of my mongo db projects.

The Problem is that when I try to login I get [object, object] but no errors.

This is what my code looks like:

user model file:

```
var db = require('../utils/oriento.js');
const OrientDB = require('orientjs');

var User = function (data) {  
  this.data = {
    name: data.name,
    email: data.email,
    password: data.password,
    id: data.id,
    rid: data.rid
  };
}

User.prototype.data = {}

User.findByID = function(id, callback){
  db.select().from('Account').where({id: id}).one()
  .then(function (user) {
    if (user === undefined) {
        return callback(false);
    } else {
        callback(new User(user));
    }
  });
}

module.exports = User;
```

So in OrientDB I have a class called Account, it has properties name, email, password and id. Currently my routes for login and register are in the app.js (to be changed later).

I am able to register, my password is successfully hashed and a new user is create.

My app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session =require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');
const OrientDB = require('orientjs');

const app = express();

// Load routes
const users = require('./routes/users');

// Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// Handlebars middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//method override middleware
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// Express Session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use(flash());
// global variables
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    next();
});

// index route
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    const title = 'welcome1';
    res.render('index', {
        title: title
    });
});
// About route
app.get('/about', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('about');
});

// User login Route
app.get('/users/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('users/login');
});

// User Register Route
app.get('/users/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('users/register');
});


// Login Form Post
app.post('/users/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true

    })(req, res, next);
});


// Register Form Post
app.post('/users/register', (req, res) => {
    var ODatabase = require('orientjs').ODatabase;
    var db = new ODatabase({
        host:     '192.168.0.107',
        port:     2424,
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'admin',
        name:     'paas1'
    });

        let name = req.body.name;
        let email = req.body.email;
        let password = req.body.password;
        let status = 'ACTIVE';

        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    password =  hash;
                    const queryString = 'insert into Account (name, password, status, email) values ' + '(' + '"' + name + '"' +',' + ' "' + password + '"' + ',' + ' "' + status + '"' + ',' + '"' + email + '"' + ')';
                    console.log(queryString);

                    db.open().then(function(){
                        return db.query(queryString);
                    });

                });
                req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now registered');
                res.redirect('/users/login');
        });
   });


const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

The oriento.js file is simply there to create a Database connection between my app and the OrientDB database. Following is the code:

```
// instantiate it once and share in multiple places(models), since it offers 
// connection pooling
// Connect to Database
var Oriento = require('orientjs');

var orientserver = Oriento({
  host: '192.168.0.107',
  port: 2424,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'mypassword'
});

var db = orientserver.use({
  name: 'paas1',
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'admin'
});

console.log('Using database: ' + db.name);

module.exports = db;
```

Lastly this is my passport.js file:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const OrientDB = require('orientjs');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const express = require('express');
const session =require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('../utils/oriento.js');
User = require("../models/user.js");
const Schema = OrientDB.Schema


// Load user model
//const User = mongoose.model('users');


module.exports = function(passport){
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'}, (email, password, done) => {


       // Match user
        db.select().from('Account').where({
            email: email
        }).one().then(user => {
            if(!user){
                return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found'});
            }
            // Match password
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                if(err) throw err;

                if(isMatch){
                    return done(null, user);
                }else{
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Password incorrect'});
                }
            })
        })
    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
        console.log('serializeUser: ' + user.id)
        done(null, user.id);
    });


    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {

        User.findByID(id, function(err, user){

            console.log(user)
            if(!err) done(null, user);
            else done(err, null)  
        })
    });


}
```

As you can see from the code, I am able to successfully get all the fileds for the user in the serializeUser function, but nothing in the deserializeUser. I am guessing the problem is not with my database connection since I am able to create new users, get their properties to the point of serialize user.

But it is not storing the user in the session i think and the desirializeUser just returns [object, object] on a blank web page instead of taking me to the index route as defined in the app.js

```
// Login Form Post
app.post('/users/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true

    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Please advise what am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding return. var User = function (data) { return this.data = { name: data.name, email: data.email, password: data.password, id: data.id, rid: data.rid };

Comment: Where should I add it. Sorry I am newbie with Node

Comment: Have you considere firebase as well. Its designed for this.

Comment: I did...but I have to work with OrientDB for now. Do you think it might be a problem how I am passing the id in deserializeUser, please also have a look at my findByID method in the model file.

Answer (score 0):

```
var db = require('../utils/oriento.js'); 
const OrientDB = require('orientjs'); 

var User = function (data) { 
    return this.data = { 
          name: data.name, 
          email: data.email, 
          password: data.password,
          id: data.id, rid: data.rid
    }; 
} 

User.prototype.data = {} ...
```

Comment: That did not work....I am still getting [object, object] and now my '/' home page for the application show the same plus my console log show
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Using database: paas1
Server started on port 5000
serializeUser: sgshht74yd6eff8ddhd355fh
undefined
[object Object]
undefined
[object Object]
undefined
[object Object]
undefined
[object Object]

Comment: Ok revert changes and try console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) in deserializeUser function

Comment: I am getting Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: data is not defined in the console log

Comment: Sorry replace data with user

Comment: did that, getting undefined
undefined
[object Object]

Comment: I just tested my findByID function in my user.js model file and its also working fine. It returned all the details of the user in the database. It seems like the problem is in the passport.js

Comment: Yes definitely. More link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637609/understanding-passport-serialize-deserialize

Comment: Anyone any help please